# MediaPipe AAR File Generation

Tags: augmented-reality, opencv3.0, aar, mediapipe

I am new to MediaPipe Framework. I went through their documentation setup and installation guide for opencv@3, bazel, homebrew. I did everything and I'm also able compile and execute their Hello World CPP file.

Now I want to generate AAR file of face_detection. Again I followed each and every step mentioned in their guide, but now I am stuck at a point where local repository of opencv@3 is not able to fetch.

I am working in MacOS Catalina -v 10.15.7

ERROR: /Users/rajeevkumar/Desktop/Android/mediapipe/third_party/BUILD:178:6: //third_party:opencv_binary depends on @macos_opencv//:opencv in repository @macos_opencv which failed to fetch. no such package '@macos_opencv//': The repository's path is "/usr/local/opt/opencv@3" (absolute: "/usr/local/opt/opencv@3") but this directory does not exist.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/aar_example:mp_face_detection_aar' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have opencv installed.
did you try running

> https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/setup_opencv.sh

if you didn't, open terminal,go to mediapipe directory and use

```
./setup_opencv.sh
```

to install opencv and add necessary path to your WORKSPACE file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I resolved this issue by reinstalling OpenCV from HomeBrew and replaced opencv@3 with /usr/local/opt/opencv@4.

Comment: @Dnveeraj could you tell me how you are replaced opencv@3 with /usr/local/opt/opencv@4